# How to remove caption in legend pie amchart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, amcharts

Demo and my code is like this :

https://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/uqoo0qbs/1/

I add :

```
"legend": {},
```

The script to view caption

My images is like this :

[image]

See pictures that I give a red color. I want to remove it, but I am confused.

Any solution to solve my problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to do it is to change the [**`valueText`**](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmLegend#valueText) property. At default this will show the `[[value]]`.

Change your `legend` object to:

```
"legend": {
   valueText : '' //or \n if you want new lines
},
```

Look [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/4fj03eck/) for a working fiddle

Comment: I need you help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38515419/how-to-disable-date-before-today-in-datetimepicker-bootstrap

Comment: @samueltoh you've found your answer :) I'm sorry, but I do need sleep sometimes :D

Comment: No problem. Thank you

Comment: I need you help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38521602/how-to-make-triangle-roll-up-with-php

Comment: Darn, too late again! But i gave you an answer anyways :)

Comment: Really I love with you people . God give you long life :) @pierreduc

Comment: @PierreDuc, Thank you very much

Comment: @PierreDuc, I need you help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39652796/why-multiple-datepicker-not-working/39652870#39652870